# How to get char array's length

Tags: array, strlen

I use a LCD display to display a not known size of text ( changes over time ). I wish to display it at the center of LCD ( 2X16 ).

I declare:

```cpp
  char t[16];
  char h[16];
  sprintf(t, "%.1f%cC %.0f%%", temperature,223, humidity);
```

Now, since I want to add additional data on a specific line and center it, I need to know it size. When using:

```cpp
sizeof(t)/(sizeof(t[0])
```

I get `16` which is the size determined and not its actual size.

How can I get the exact number of chars **used**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function I think you are looking for is `strlen` - STRing LENgth.

It counts the number of characters in a string up until it finds the "NULL" end of string marker.

```
Serial.println(strlen(t));
```

Comment: well my guess was it refers to String only

Comment: `strlen` is for C strings (NULL-terminated character arrays).  For `String` you want `String.length()`.

Comment: @Guy.D the code you posted is using char arrays, not `String` objects. Majenko's answer is what you need, not `String.length()`. Note that you need to be careful not to overflow your char array. That will cause undefined behavior (read "bugs.")